# Is it ok to change public storage folder name from 'public/storage' to 'public/public'?

Tags: laravel

Laravel recommends [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#configuration) to create symlink from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`.  I'm looking for some inputs on whether renaming `public/storage` to `public/public` would cause any issues in other configurations or packages.

I am doing this because all my filenames in db are relative to `storage/app` folder.  I store it that way since I can then uniformly retrieve any file using `storage_path()` helper.  For example:

1. Protected file: `storage/app/internal/secret.doc` => filename in db = `internal/secret.doc`
2. Public file: `storage/app/public/common.doc` => filename in db = `public/common.doc`

Then to retrieve them:

```
// get filename 'internal/secret.doc' or 'public/common.doc'
$filename = DB::table('files')->find(1)->value('name'); // find file where id=1 and get only the name field
$file = storage_path('app/'.$filename);
```

This way I don't have to wonder whether I need to add `public/` folder while retrieving a specific file.  Also when I use `asset()` helper to generate urls to public files, again I can simply say:

```
$url = asset($filename)`;
```

Whereas, if I continue to use `public/storage` as the symlinked folder then I would have to do:

```
$temp_filename = str_replace('public/', '', $filename);
$url = asset('storage/'.$temp_filename);
```

Let me know if you have a different take or spot some issues with the renaming.

Answer (score 1):

Once `public/storage` is sym linked to `storage/app/public`, you don't want your filepath in `asset()` to reference `public`.  Public folder is already the root of your webserver, and `asset()` assumes public directory base.  So your asset would be in `asset("storage/$filename")`. That actually pulls from `storage/app/public/$filename`.

Comment: I agree with public being root folder already.  My main focus is storing filenames in db with a common naming convention, which is the entire path after storage/app/.  With what you've mentioned my filename cannot be stored as  'public/common.doc'.  Here the public refers to folder app/storage/public.  If I don't have a common naming convention then it becomes problematic to manipulate the names to figure out which folder to include or remove while calling storage_path() and asset()

Comment: hmm, I see what you mean. I guess it makes sense though, that you would have a different system or a couple separate functions, to help you distinguish between files in `storage/public` and `storage/foo`. Since files in the public folder are accessible to the public, you want to be careful!  Rather than store in that folder using `storage_path('app/public')` I would store files there using `public_path('storage')` which resolves to the same place.  This ensures public files and private files never get mixed up.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff, yes, it would be good to use public_path('storage') but there are times when I don't know whether the filename from db is protected or public to make a choice between storage_path() and public_path().  Else, I might have to store this additional information in db, maybe in a field like 'access_type'.

Comment: What are you storing that is sometimes public and sometimes not public? It seems that these things should be kept separate in your application logic, not your database logic.